# Custom Control Update Dependency property from view model

Tags: c#, wpf, custom-controls, dependency-properties

I'm having an issue with my custom control.  when i raise notify property changed, the getter of my property is never called.  I've searched around and I don't think I'm breaking my binding (although i could be wrong).
My control is as follows:


XAML

```
<UserControl x:Class="ClassNamespace.ClassName"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:mui="http://firstfloorsoftware.com/ModernUI"
         xmlns:default="clr-namespace:PullTabs.Applications.FrontEnd.Views.Default"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"
         >

<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <TextBlock Text="Sample Text" />
    <DataGrid Grid.Row="1" FontSize="20" ItemsSource="{Binding Bills, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type default:ClassName}}}" />
    <TextBlock Text="Sample Text" />
</Grid>
```

The code behind is:

```
public partial class ClassName
{
    public static DependencyProperty TransactionsProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Transactions",
        typeof (IEnumerable<Transaction>), typeof (BillCounts),
        new UIPropertyMetadata(new List<Transaction>(), OnTransactionsPropertyPropertyChangedCallback));

    private static void OnTransactionsPropertyPropertyChangedCallback(DependencyObject source,
        DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        UpdateBillCounts((IEnumerable<Transaction>) e.NewValue);
    }

    public static ObservableCollection<Bill> Bills { get; } = new ObservableCollection<Bill>();

    public IEnumerable<Transaction> Transactions
    {
        get { return (IEnumerable<Transaction>) GetValue(TransactionsProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TransactionsProperty, value); }
    }

    public BillCounts()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private static void UpdateBillCounts(IEnumerable<Transaction> transactions)
    {
        var lifetimeBillsAccepted = new Dictionary<decimal, int>();
        Bills.Clear();
        foreach (var bill in transactions)
        {
            if (lifetimeBillsAccepted.ContainsKey(bill.Amount))
            {
                lifetimeBillsAccepted[bill.Amount] = lifetimeBillsAccepted[bill.Amount] + 1;
            }
            else
            {
                lifetimeBillsAccepted.Add(bill.Amount, 1);
            }
        }
        foreach (var bill in lifetimeBillsAccepted)
        {
            Bills.Add(new Bill($"{bill.Key:C2}", bill.Value));
        }

        Bills.Add(new Bill("Total", Bills.Sum(bill => bill.Count)));

    }
}
```

it is used like this:

```
<Default:BillCounts Grid.Column="0" Margin="0,10" Transactions="{Binding PeriodTransactions}" />
```

PeriodTransactions is defined like so:

```
public IEnumerable<Transaction> PeriodTransactions
    {
        get
        {
            _periodTransactions = _periodTransactions ?? GetMyDataFromDB();
            return _periodTransactions;
        }
    }
```

where PeriodTransactions is a valid readonly property containing valid data for the dependency property.

When I click a button and it's method is fired I run these two lines of code:

```
_periodTransactions = GetMyDatFromDB();
RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(PeriodTransactions));
```

I would expect that the getter of the PeriodTransactions property would then execute as i am explicitly calling the property changed method naming the PeriodTransactions property.  However, with my breakpoint set in the getter, it is only called when my view is created, and never again.  Please provide some insight as to why my dependency property in my custom control isn't updating or why the getter isn't being called by my custom control's dependency property.

Comment: Is the UpdateBillCounts method invoked on the initial binding?

Comment: yes it is.  it all works for initial binding

Comment: Is it possible that `GetMyDataFromDB` always returns the same collection instance? Your code would only work if it returns a new `IEnumerable<Transaction>` on each call.

Comment: I would agree if the breakpoint in my getter was being hit.  Also i know it is not returning the same data because if i leave and then enter the view again, the custom control has the correct data as the getter was hit.